# How to safely perform type-punning in embedded system

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, strict-aliasing, type-punning

Our team is currently using some ported code from an old architecture to a new product based on the ARM Cortex M3 platform using a customized version of GCC 4.5.1. We are reading data from a communications link, and attempting to cast the raw byte array to a struct to cleanly parse the data. After casting the pointer to a struct and dereferencing, we are getting a warning: "dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules".

After some research, I've realized that since the char array has no alignment rules and the struct have to be word aligned, casting the pointers causes undefined behavior (a Bad Thing). I'm wondering if there is a better way to do what we're trying.

I know we can explicitly word-align the char array using GCC's "**attribute** ((aligned (4)))". I believe this will make our code "safer", but the warnings will still clutter up our builds, and I don't want to disable the warnings in case this situation arises again. What we want is a way to safely do what we are trying, that will still inform us if we attempt to do something unsafe in another place later. Since this is an embedded system, RAM  usage and flash usage are important to some degree.

Portability (compiler and architecture) is not a huge concern, this is just for one product. However, if a portable solution exists, it would be preferred.

Here is the a (very simplified) example of what we are currently doing:

```
#define MESSAGE_TYPE_A 0
#define MESSAGE_TYPE_B 1

typedef struct MessageA __attribute__((__packed__))
{
    unsigned char  messageType;
    unsigned short data1;
    unsigned int   data2;
}

typedef struct MessageB __attribute__((__packed__))
{
    unsigned char  messageType;
    unsigned char  data3;
    unsigned char  data4;
}


// This gets filled by the comm system, assume from a UART interrupt or similar
unsigned char data[100];


// Assume this gets called once we receive a full message
void ProcessMessage()
{
    MessageA* messageA;
    unsigned char messageType = data[0];

    if (messageType == MESSAGE_TYPE_A)
    {
        // Cast data to struct and attempt to read
        messageA = (MessageA*)data; // Not safe since data may not be word aligned
                                    // This may cause undefined behavior

        if (messageA->data1 == 4) // warning would be here, when we use the data at the pointer
        {
            // Perform some action...
        }
    }
    // ...
    // process different types of messages
}
```

Comment: As a comment, the warning is not just about unaligned accesses, and it's warning of a genuine problem.  The problem is that GCC does some optimizations that assume that data of different types cannot alias each other, and it may reorder accesses or other things based on that assumption -- potentially leading to incorrect results if the data does actually alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cortex M3 can handle unaligned accesses just fine.  I have done this in similar packet processing systems with the M3.  You don't need to do anything, you can just use the flag -fno-strict-aliasing to get rid of the warning.

Comment: Is this the case for the entire RAM, or are there limitations?

Comment: The Cortex can do unaligned reads/writes for any address, RAM, ROM, etc.  You should disregard all the comments people are giving about having to use unions or avoiding packed structures.  What they are saying is true for some CPUs or writing portable code.  In embedded systems doing packet processing you usually don't have a choice about your incoming data alignment.  It's most efficient in code size and speed to just to let the CPU handle the unaligned access.

Comment: -fno-strict-aliasing turns off a very useful optimization. Sure, it works around certain problems with badly written code, and yes it makes annoying warnings go away in ok code that smells bad to the compiler (like this), but really, I would never recommend using that option.

Comment: @ams, the point is that in an embedded system doing packet processing, you often have no control over the alignment of the data structures because you are dealing with packed packet formats.  In that case you either just do an unaligned access (which is no problem for most embedded CPUs, and definitely OK on a cortex M3) or you do a copy of the data from the unaligned area to an aligned struct (way less efficient).  It has nothing to do with "badly written code"

Comment: @TJD trust me, if you have to disable bits of the compiler and tell it to disregard the C standard then it's badly written code. No ifs, no buts, no quotes.

Comment: @ams, the original post specifically says portability isn't an issue.  When engineering an embedded systems, practical considerations are more important than philosophical ones.

Comment: @TLD nonsense, I've posted the proper solution to fix the issue! Does that not look practical? Sorry, I've been working in embedded systems for 12 years now, and I've never seen a good excuse for sloppy programming. The language gives you all the power you need. In my experience, embedded developers are usually *more* interested in getting every last bit of efficiency from the compiler, not less. If you turn off strict aliasing the compiler is forced to do hundreds or thousands of unnecessary memory writes, just in case two pointers happen to be aliases. And then somebody insults the compiler.

Comment: Although the Cortex M3 will a simple 32-bit load and store instruction correctly with unaligned data, compilers may replace a pair of accesses to consecutive addresses with a LDM (load multiple), STM (store multiple), or other instruction which will only support aligned accesses.

Answer (score 6):

As has already been pointed out, casting pointers about is a dodgy practice.

Solution: use a union

```
struct message {
  unsigned char messageType;
  union {
    struct {
      int data1;
      short data2;
    } A;
    struct {
      char data1[5];
      int data2;
    } B;
  } data;
};

void func (...) {
  struct message msg;
  getMessage (&msg);

  switch (msg.messageType) {
    case TYPEA:
      doStuff (msg.data.A.data1);
      break;
    case TYPEB:
      doOtherStuff (msg.data.B.data1);
      break;
  }
}
```

By this means the compiler knows you're accessing the same data via different means, and the warnings and Bad Things will go away.

Of coure, you'll need to make sure the structure alignment and packing matches your message format. Beware endian issues and such if the machine on the other end of the link doesn't match.

Answer (score 4):

Type punning through cast of types different than `char *` or a pointer to a signed/unsigned variant of `char` is not strictly conforming as it violates C aliasing rules (and sometimes alignment rules if no care is given).

However, `gcc` permits type punning through union types. Manpage of `gcc` explicitly documents it:

> The practice of reading from a different union member than the one most recently    written to (called "type-punning") is common.  Even with
>              -fstrict-aliasing, type-punning is allowed, provided the memory is accessed through the union type.

To disable optimizations related to aliasing rules with `gcc` (and thus allow the program to break C aliasing rules), the program can be compiled with:  `-fno-strict-aliasing`. Note that with this option enabled, the program is no longer strictly conforming, but you said portability is not a concern. For information, the Linux kernel is compiled with this option.

Comment: You're suggesting I could have a union with every single message structure, then perform a single memcpy from the buffer into a local union type? That may work, and probably wouldn't be too painful in RAM or Flash space.

Comment: @shenles structure types have different alignments than arrays of `char` and a structure of type `struct A` may have a different alignment than a structure of type `struct B`. Using a union of the different structure (or the structures and the array of `char`) let you have the correct alignment for these types.

Comment: You could have a union with every message type AND a char array in it.  Then you read the packet directly into the char array in the union and the access it via the other union fields.

Answer (score 2):

GCC has a `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag that will disable strict-aliasing-based optimizations and make your code safe.

If you're really looking for a way to "fix" it, you have to rethink the way your code works.  You can't just overlay the structure the way you're trying, so you need to do something like this:

```
MessageA messageA;
messageA.messageType = data[0];
// Watch out - endianness and `sizeof(short)` dependent!
messageA.data1 = (data[1] << 8) + data[2];
// Watch out - endianness and `sizeof(int)` dependent!
messageA.data2 = (data[3] << 24) + (data[4] << 16)
               + (data[5] <<  8) + data[6];
```

This method will let you avoid packing your structure, which might also improve its performance characteristics elsewhere in your code.  Alternately:

```
MessageA messageA;
memcpy(&messageA, data, sizeof messageA);
```

Will do it with your packed structures.  You would do the reverse operations to translate the structures back into a flat buffer if necessary.

Comment: So that will guarantee that the char array is aligned on the word boundary? I saw this option, but was under the impression that it wouldn't fix the underlying problem of variable alignment.

Comment: @shenles - absolutely not.  If your compiler is going to insist on making word accesses at unaligned offsets, you're probably out of luck with *any* packed structure situation.  If you have a problem like that, you'll need to use one of the examples in my answer as a way to translate your structures to and from the `char` array.

Comment: Though, if you annotate the structs as `packed`, gcc will generate safe code on access to those members that would otherwise result in unaligned access, the generated code would be pretty similar to the bitwise ops here. (At least for XScale, I don't know if that holds for all targets)

Comment: We were hoping to avoid manually parsing the data out of the byte stream, since our packets might be hundreds of bytes and have tens of items. The goal of casting to a struct was to avoid changing the parsing code every time a new piece of data was added or a size of something changed... The memcpy is probably the safest way, but I'm a bit worried about flash usage if we have to add memcpy for every single type of message (again, there could be 100s).

Comment: Most compilers inline trivial uses of memcpy() like these, the code will hardly be larger than a plain assignment.

Comment: Even if the memcpy() implementation is only 20 bytes in the Thumb instructions, 20 * 100 uses = 2K of our 64K gone. The nice thing about type-punning is it can be virtually free, flash space wise.

Comment: A worse thing about memcpy is that even on compilers with sensible aliasing logic it forces the compiler to assume that the source and destination might alias anything of any type, while more sensible aliasing logic would recognize that given `*uint16_t p;`, the expression `*((uint32_t*)p)=23;` may alias things of type uint16_t or uint32_t, but not `double` or a pointer type.

Answer (score 2):

Stop using packed structures and `memcpy` the individual fields into variables of the correct size and type. This is the safe, portable, clean way to do what you're trying to achieve. If you're lucky, gcc will optimize the tiny fixed-size `memcpy` into a few simple load and store instructions.

Comment: Adding a memcpy for each argument of a message, time the number of messages would be fairly wasteful to our code-space and performance. This is an embedded system, with a very real memory cap (about 64K flash total in our case).

Comment: Like I said, the compiler should compile it to the same load instructions as an assignment "would be" if the assignment were valid.

Answer (score 0):

For unaligned accesses, look at the linux macros get_unaligned/put_unaligned.