# Solutions to “dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules” warning

Tags: c++, linux, networking, g++

Many solutions are proposed:

1. [How to safely perform type-punning in embedded system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011884/how-to-safely-perform-type-punning-in-embedded-system)
2. ["dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163126/dereferencing-type-punned-pointer-will-break-strict-aliasing-rules-warning)

I would like to know:

1. How is **attribute**((**may_alias**)) solution different from union solution in terms of performance?  Because both basically ask GCC not to do any
   alignment optimization.
2. Is there a better solution for the receiver in processing incoming binary messages over network? Given that the sender sends data in C struct format with **packed** attribute?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The other solution is _not_ to break strict-aliasing rules...?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit are you suggesting to use non-packed struct as the format of message?  If yes, it would mean both sender and server should have the same architecture (i.e. 64-bit).

Comment: Don't break aliasing rules and (mem)copy via a char* buffer?

Comment: Right, memcpy is another option...I didn't list it in my post because I *feel* it might be slower than __may_alias__

Comment: Actually, I remember I did measure memcpy() vs ignoring alignment warning (using casting) I think.  ignoring alignment is 25-75% faster than memcpy().